# Where can I ask about wifi problems?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a really weird wifi problem with just my laptop. On my phone etc. it works. When I connect with a cable to my laptop it works.

Is there a Stack Exchange website for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can ask on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - **personal and home computer networking**

[What is on-topic there](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)